# flutter routing not routing

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, materialpageroute

I'm building an amazon clone app, currently building the sign up function of the app. I run into the following problem is when I as a user sign up for an account and click on sign up there happen's nothing. How the code is setup it should reroute back to the sign in page:

this is the code:

```
`Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (_) =>
                                                const SignInScreen()));
```

There happens litteraly zero. It should route from the sign up page to the sign in page but doesn't do that.

I tried creating a route from a sign up button back to a sign in screen with the use of MaterialPageRoute to the SigninScreen. It loads for a second then stops and stays in the same sign up screen. While still adding the account to the firebase database.

Comment: Why don't you do directly Navigator.pop on signup button once you receive success response in api?

Comment: doesn't work either, I'm doing a tutorial here and I already asked the creator but he doesn't answer. I think it's a difference between flutter versions.

Comment: Share your tutorial resource

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmY87B1LlPk&t=6038s&ab_channel=AadhiArun